# order of object files in static library

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, static-linking, unix-ar

I know that when linking to multiple static libraries or object files, the order matters (dependent libraries should be listed before their dependencies).  I want to know if, when creating a library file with `ar`, this same rule applies and the order within the library matters, or within the same `.a` file it doesn't make a difference.
I am packing 200+ object files with a complicated dependency graph, and doing

```
ar rcs mylib.a objs/*.o
```

is considerably easier then listing them in the correct order.

I am using `gcc`, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order within the library *used* to matter long time ago.

It no longer matters on any UNIX system newer than ~15-20 years. From `man ranlib`:

```
   An archive with such an index speeds up linking to the library
   and allows routines in the library to call each other without
   regard to their placement in the archive.
```

Most non-ancient UNIX systems either produce the `__.SYMDEF` (which contains above index) automatically while building the archive library, or build it in-memory at link time.

Comment: *"The order within the library used to matter long time ago...."* - that's not necessarily true due to C++ static object initialization order.